# GIT: How to insert only a modification in two branch not allowing the two projects are equal

Tags: git, branch, push, commit

I have the master branch that from it I created two applications, I made a commit in application A, however realized that this modification is common in both branch.
How do I enter just this change in the two branch not allowing the two projects are equal.

Comment: *How do I enter just this change in the two branch not allowing the two projects are equal.* Please clarify...

Comment: basically i want to copy commits from one branch to another

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can *cherry pick* the commits between branches.

- Find the commit in the *A* branch (e.g. *A1234B*)
- Checkout branch *B*: `git checkout B`
- Cherry-pick the commit: `git cherry-pick A1234B`

This will apply the commit from hash *A1234B* on the *B* branch as a new commit - it will not merge the branches. A tool like SourceTree will make this process a lot easier, since you can find the commit from the project history, and you can cherry-pick multiple commits at the same time.

Here's a more detailed example: https://ariejan.net/2010/06/10/cherry-picking-specific-commits-from-another-branch/

Having said that, I find it rather strange to have two different applications in branches in the same repository - but I don't know your exact setup.

Answer (score 0):

As you said that the commit which you have done in Application A is also needs to be added in Application B assuming that the change (commit) is related to the common code which is available in both of these applications.

Then you can switch the branch to application B

```
git checkout branch_name
```

then [apply the patch](https://ariejan.net/2009/10/26/how-to-create-and-apply-a-patch-with-git/) of the commit

```
git apply patch_file
```

or rather than applying patch you can again make changes in Application B branch.

After that commit and push the code.

You can always make changes to any of the branch and there is as such no compulsion that different branches of same repository needs to be equal.